# Memory issue/error in Java

Tags: java

Below is a method I have in an adventure game I am making in Java:

```
public static void characterDisperse(){

    int wRand = (int)(Math.random())*wModifiers.length;
    Item[] inv = new Item[1];
    inv[0]=new Item(wModifiers[wRand] + " " + wNames[(int)(Math.random()*wNames.length)],(int)(Math.random()*wModifiers.length)*2,1);
    for(int a=0;a<10;a++){
        for(int b=0;b<10;b++){
            if(Math.random()>0.5){ //density of characters
                charTest[a][b] = new Character(names[(int)(Math.random()*names.length)],(int)(Math.random()*5),(int)(Math.random()*3),(int)(Math.random()*15+5)*10,2,inv); 

                map[a][b].chars[1] = charTest[a][b];
                System.out.println(map[a][b].chars[1]);

            }
            else{
                map[a][b].passable = false;
            }


        }
    }
    for(int d=0;d<10;d++){
        for(int e=0;e<10;e++){
            System.out.println(map[d][e].chars[1]);
        }
    }

}
```

The problem I am having is that in the first double "for" loop, each character printed is a different character with all sorts of different attributes. However, when the second double "for" loop runs and prints out all of the characters I just created, it prints out all the same character, see below:

```
NAME: Moriah    RACE: 4 ALIGNMENT: 0    HEALTH: 130 SKILL: 2    INVENTORY: 1
NAME: Marge RACE: 1 ALIGNMENT: 0    HEALTH: 160 SKILL: 2    INVENTORY: 1
NAME: Faith RACE: 0 ALIGNMENT: 1    HEALTH: 50  SKILL: 2    INVENTORY: 1
NAME: Morton    RACE: 3 ALIGNMENT: 2    HEALTH: 60  SKILL: 2    INVENTORY: 1
NAME: Sherwood  RACE: 1 ALIGNMENT: 2    HEALTH: 50  SKILL: 2    INVENTORY: 1
NAME: Ezequiel  RACE: 2 ALIGNMENT: 1    HEALTH: 150 SKILL: 2    INVENTORY: 1
NAME: Herschel  RACE: 2 ALIGNMENT: 2    HEALTH: 70  SKILL: 2    INVENTORY: 1
NAME: Lester    RACE: 3 ALIGNMENT: 2    HEALTH: 80  SKILL: 2    INVENTORY: 1
NAME: Corinna   RACE: 2 ALIGNMENT: 0    HEALTH: 190 SKILL: 2    INVENTORY: 1

FIRST FOR LOOP ENDS HERE
SECOND FOR LOOP BEGINS

NAME: Corinna   RACE: 2 ALIGNMENT: 0    HEALTH: 190 SKILL: 2    INVENTORY: 1
NAME: Corinna   RACE: 2 ALIGNMENT: 0    HEALTH: 190 SKILL: 2    INVENTORY: 1
NAME: Corinna   RACE: 2 ALIGNMENT: 0    HEALTH: 190 SKILL: 2    INVENTORY: 1
NAME: Corinna   RACE: 2 ALIGNMENT: 0    HEALTH: 190 SKILL: 2    INVENTORY: 1
NAME: Corinna   RACE: 2 ALIGNMENT: 0    HEALTH: 190 SKILL: 2    INVENTORY: 1
NAME: Corinna   RACE: 2 ALIGNMENT: 0    HEALTH: 190 SKILL: 2    INVENTORY: 1
NAME: Corinna   RACE: 2 ALIGNMENT: 0    HEALTH: 190 SKILL: 2    INVENTORY: 1
NAME: Corinna   RACE: 2 ALIGNMENT: 0    HEALTH: 190 SKILL: 2    INVENTORY: 1
```

I believe it is some sort of memory issue where I set the character at map[a][b] (a location object) to the character in charTest[a][b]. charTest has already been instantiated earlier in the code.

map[][] is a 10x10 array of Location objects, and charTest[][] is a 10x10 array of Character objects:

Location.java:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Location{

Character[] chars;
Feature[] features;
boolean passable;

public Location(Character[] chars, Feature[] features, boolean passable){
    this.chars = chars;
    this.features = features;
    this.passable = passable;
}

public String toString(){
    return "test";
}

public boolean containsChars(Location l){
    if(l.chars.length>0){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

Character.java:

```
public class Character{
String name;  
int race;
int alignment;

int health;

int skill;

Item[] inventory;

public Character(String name,int race,int alignment,int health,int skill,Item[] inventory){
    this.name = name;
    this.race = race;
    this.alignment = alignment;
    this.health = health;
    this.skill = skill;
    this.inventory = inventory;
}


public String toString(){
    String printOut = "NAME: " + name + "\tRACE: " + race + "\tALIGNMENT: " + alignment + "\tHEALTH: " + health + "\tSKILL: " + skill + "\tINVENTORY: " + "1";
    return printOut;
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `(int)(Math.random()*wNames.length)`, you should create a `Random rnd = new Random()`, then use `rnd.nextInt(wNames.length)`. Better distribution, easier to read/understand, and no casting.

Comment: What does the structure of `map` and `charTest` look like?

Comment: Without seeing the implementation of `Character`, we can't be sure what is wrong. Likely candidate is that you're using `static` fields.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint and comparing your data?

Comment: can you show the code where you create and fill the map array?

Answer (score 1):

In this line, you have to change the `inv` at the end to `new Item[1]`

```
charTest[a][b] = new Character(names[(int)(Math.random()*names.length)],(int)(Math.random()*5),(int)(Math.random()*3),(int)(Math.random()*15+5)*10,2,inv);
```

So this line would do the job :

```
charTest[a][b] = new Character(names[(int)(Math.random()*names.length)],(int)(Math.random()*5),(int)(Math.random()*3),(int)(Math.random()*15+5)*10,2,new Item[1]);
```

The reason is, when you create array with this `Item[] inv = new Item[1];`, the **reference** to this array is assigned to variable `inv`. Then if you assing the value `inv` to another variable you **copy** the **reference**.

It means that in your case, all `Character` objects have the same object.

---

You obviously have **the same problem** in your

```
map[a][b].chars[1]
```

When you create `map[a][b]`, you assing the same `chars` array to all fields in `map`.

Then you every time create new `Character`, you place him into the same `chars` array, which replace the old and prints it. Thats why you see new characters while generating them and thats why the last one is same in all the `map` variable.

---

When you generating initial data for map, you have to create new arrays for each Location, something like this :

```
for(int a=0;a<10;a++){
        for(int b=0;b<10;b++){
            map[a][b] = new Location(new Character[5], new Feature[5], true);
        }
}
```

PS : I would strongly recommend to use ArrayLists, instead of arrays.

Comment: IMHO he wants to use the same inventory for each character. I don't see any problem with that. Possibly even passing null (if it's acceptable) to each of them wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Gavriel - no, it is mistake and I am pretty sure he actually did the same assign to the `map[a][b].chars[1]`, which caused the problem.

Comment: so all characters have a reference to the same inventory. It seems that's logical in terms of the game logic, and I still see why that is a problem in the code

Comment: @Gavriel - all characters have same inventory? So you play Diablo 3 and you have same inventory as all other players?

Comment: he creates a new Character, with whatever "garbage" references. The name is a reference to a String. It is only being copied (the reference) to the new Character object, then printed out in the same for loop. Nothing changes the name in the code (unless there are other threads we don't know about) then in the 2nd for loop he prints them out. All the other "garbage" however illogically referencing each other, doesn't seem to change anyhing if we only look at the name. Still in the 2nd loop we only see the last name repeating

Comment: @Gavriel - did you read my WHOLE answer? On actual problem, which he shown us (the inventory), I told him where the real issue is, because it is same principle. He somewhere creates array of `Characters` and then he assing this array to all the `Location` objects stored in `Location map[][]` and thats why he has same array of `Character` objects in every single field in `Location map[][]`.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try to rewrite your code in a way that anybody, including yourself, can understand it? If your code looks like this, it is no wonder that you get lost in it.

- Variablenames like wRand and inv don't tell what they do
- Split the Code-Blob in small methods and give them a good name
- The Character Constructor call is insane. Refactor it and maybe apply the factory pattern
- Create single Functions that do one thing, like randomizing Race, Name, Health, etc.
- Use Collections instead of Arrays if possible
- Don't use magic numbers all over your code.
- Try to avoid an indentation level of 3 and nested loops